Convert String in Float
I want to convert a string to float
bool numbFloat = float.TryParse(operatorsOperand[0], out float numFloat);
System.Console.WriteLine(numFloat);
return result;

For example: I have a string[0] where the number 5,4 is..when I convert it to float and then print it, 54 appears, it appears like that regardless of which conversion method I use, float.Parse, TryParse, Convert...

What is operatorsOperand?  What is result?  Can you update this to a [mcve] which can be independently tested to demonstrate the problem?

Chances are this boils down to a locale/culture issue. "5,4" in some European countries would be 5.4. Not so in most other countries, where "." is the decimal-separator. So, if the current culture is not for example de-de, then the string "5,4" will be parsed to "54" because that "," would be ignored (or if using strict parsing, it would fail).

Afaik it is recommended to be explicit about the culture you want to parse in. That way the underlying system culture doesn't matter (that much). If you know you are going to parse German or French - formatted numbers, pass the respective culture.

If you use a specific culture that use , as the decimal separator, it works as expected
var de = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
bool numbFloat = float.TryParse("5,4", de, out float numFloat);
System.Console.WriteLine(numFloat);

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tVxF1E
